# Inverse of an element in an external direct product

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G = \mathbb{Z}_{4}\times S_{5}$

What is the inverse of $\left ( 3,\left ( 1,2 \right )\left ( 3,5 \right ) \right )?$

The inverse of any elements a in $\mathbb{Z}_{4}$ is 4-a. So the inverse of 3 is 1.

The inverse of the permutation is just $\left ( 5,3 \right )\left ( 2,1 \right ) right?$

My solution is showing a different answer to the inverse permutation. Permutation is giving me a lot of problems.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes, that does seem to be correct.  What's the answer your book gives?

Comment: $(1,2)(3,5)$ is what it gives. 
Seems pretty standard that the inverse is just the reversal of each cycle and reversing the elements in each cycle.

Comment: Note that $(1,2) (3,5)$ and $(5,3)(2,1)$ are different ways of writing the same element in $S_5$.

Comment: They're the same - $(1, 2)$ is the same as $(2, 1)$. It's telling you to swap $1$ with $2$.